# Angular - Duplicated Side Nav

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to angular, using angular 10 to create a simple page with side bar and footer with angular material components. I am facing issues to display the left / side nav correctly. It is currently getting duplicated.
Code and Snapshot as below

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TITLE</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

appcomponent.html

```
<app-container></app-container>
```

container.component.html

```
<div class="example-container" [class.example-is-mobile]="mobileQuery.matches" >
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="example-toolbar">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    <h1 class="example-app-name">GDFD Admin UI</h1>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container"
                         [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
    <mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
                 [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" fixedTopGap="56">
      <!-- <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{nav}}</a>
        <a>Link</a>
      </mat-nav-list> -->
      <mat-nav-list>
        <mat-list-item>
          <span>Configurations</span>
          <mat-icon mat-list-icon>home</mat-icon>

        </mat-list-item>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/admin-settings'"> Manage Admin Settings </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/auto-job-settings'"> Manage Auto Job Settings </a>
      </mat-nav-list>
      <mat-nav-list>
        <mat-list-item>
          <span>Reports</span>
          <mat-icon mat-list-icon>assessment</mat-icon>

        </mat-list-item>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/audittrail'"> Audit Trail Report </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/exception-report'"> Exception Report </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/lock-by-etb'"> Locked By ETB </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/logs-export'"> Logs Export </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/process-run-report'"> Process Run Report </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/process-run-summary'"> Process Run Summary </a>

      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <p>Dummy Rightside Content</p>

     <div class="mat-app-background basic-container">
      <!-- Pages get rendered in the below tag -->
      <router-outlet>Loading...</router-outlet>

    </div>

    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
  <!-- <app-footer></app-footer> -->
</div>
```

[image]
[image: Snapshot]

[image: Snaoshot 2]

Please advise what is the mistake ? also my app does not load in IE 11. Please help.

Comment: If you check your HTML code, you are duplication the call of </mat-sidenav>

Comment: There are not duplicates, its just another list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is a caching issue, restarting everything worked

Comment: Could you please add what cache you cleared and what exactly you restarted? I'm having this on v14, new installation.